# How to use special character in NSURL?

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsurlsession

My application is using an NSURL like this:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=Aïn+Béïda+Algeria&country=")
```

When I tried to make a task for getting data from this NSURL like this:

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("urlContent \(urlContent!)")
        } else {

            println("error mode")
        }
```

but I got error when trying to got data from that address, although when I using safari  go to link: "http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=Aïn+Béïda+Algeria&country=" I can see the data. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Swift 2**

```
let original = "http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=Aïn+Béïda+Algeria&country="
if let encodedString = original.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(
    NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet()),
    url = NSURL(string: encodedString) 
{
    print(url)
}
```

Encoded URL is now:

> "http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=A%C3%AFn+B%C3%A9%C3%AFda+Algeria&country="

and is compatible with `NSURLSession`.

**Swift 3**

```
let original = "http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=Aïn+Béïda+Algeria&country="
if let encoded = original.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: encoded)
{
    print(url)
}
```

Comment: why `URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet`? there is also `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet`, `URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet`, `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet`, `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` and `URLUserAllowedCharacterSet`

Comment: @fabb I could have used URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet to the same effect, both sets are complete. The other URL character sets are subsets of these two.

Comment: thanks for the info. Have you got some source for that info?

Comment: The source is my own tests: with [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/ericdke/fe3dea5a9b2cac9edd88) I've compared the content of each URL character set. You can see the result [here](https://gist.github.com/ericdke/3b87601583a77b856293ab330b8bd4cc).

Comment: I have two problems with this code snipet: 1. You should *never* encode an entire query string at once.  Certain characters are reserved as delimiters between query string parts (&, =, etc.), and if the original strings that make up those query parts contain any of those characters, your approach will break very badly.  2. You should be using NSURLComponents to construct the query string instead of using string concatenation.  It is much safer, and it avoids you having to worry about character sets at all.