# swift - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when searching in Google Images

Tags: json, swift, image, google-image-search

```
let placeName = "New York"

func getImage(place: String) {
let url = NSURL(string: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=\(place)")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){ (response, go, error) -> Void in
    do {
        let go = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(go!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
        let responseData = go["responseData"] as! [String:AnyObject]
        let results = responseData["results"] as! [[String:String]]
        let firstObject = results[0]
        let firstURL = firstObject["unescapedUrl"]
        print(responseData)
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }

  }
}

getImage(placeName)
```

It looks like when I want to grab an image from Google Images, it won't work. Can someone please figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to encode your URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148999/how-to-use-special-character-in-nsurl and to stop force-unwrapping your optionals.

Answer (score -1):

Your URL is badly formatted. Delete the space between New and York.