# How to send '&' character in HTTP request body?

Tags: swift, post, http-post

I have these parameters saved as string :

```
title=Culture, sport & recreation (1 day)&useremail=ammar@gmail.com&days=2&ispredefined=false&languageid=1&websiteid=1&node=item&languageid=1&websiteid=1&moduletype=Accommodation&moduleuniquename=abu.dhabi.plaza.hotel.apartments&dayindex=1
```

and I am passing it to a request body using the below code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.getURL(url)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```

but the problem is that the title in the string **title=Culture, sport & recreation** has '&'character and i am getting 400 bad Request from the server

please any advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try using && @ammar arangy

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/30149081/2227743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in the attached links you have to encode the ampersand sign.

> encodeURIComponent('&') gives "%26"

Thus, you have to replace all ampersands with %26 or use [encodeURIComponent(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in your code.

[escaping ampersand in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url)

[How can I send the "&" (ampersand) character via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294107/how-can-i-send-the-ampersand-character-via-ajax)

Comment: Thanks very much @Stefan Dolezel