# Convert String to UTF8String - Swift - iOS - XMLParser

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, utf

I have this String -

`&to[]=0532332028&to[]=0532332027`

I want to convert this String to (**UTF8**)  -

`%26to%5B%5D%3D0532332028%26to%5B%5D%3D0532332027`

I already try this Code -

```
let str = String(UTF8String: "&to[]=0532332028&to[]=0532332027".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean, Converting a string to HTML-safe encoding? This has very little to do with UTF-8 directly.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Yes, I am new in Swift. Can you please suggest steps?
Now I have  - "&to[]=0532332028&to[]=0532332027"
I want  - "%26to%5B%5D%3D0532332028%26to%5B%5D%3D0532332027"
I mean HTML encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148999/how-to-use-special-character-in-nsurl (use the percent-encoding part)

Comment: I pass through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148999/how-to-use-special-character-in-nsurl , But still not get Answer.

Comment: Thanks Antwan van Houdt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the string to UTF8, you can follow the code

```
    let text = "&to[]=0532332028&to[]=0532332027"
    let encodeText = text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    print("encodeText : \(encodeText)")
```

**Output** :
encodeText : &to%5B%5D=0532332028&to%5B%5D=0532332027

But by the above code, you won't get %26 for "&", If you want it
You can create a custom method to replace "&" with "%26" by using "`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`" method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.
Another Solution - 

let strNew = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
            nil,
            "&to[]=0532332028&to[]=0532332027",
            nil,
            "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
            CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
        )

 print("encodeText : \(strNew)")

Comment: @kushThakkar, Hmm.. but the method is deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code:

```
let text = "&to[]=0532332028&to[]=0532332027"
let output = text.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
```

The output:

```
"%26to%5B%5D%3D0532332028%26to%5B%5D%3D0532332027"
```