# add quotes mark to string

Tags: string, swift3, concatenation

I want to concatenate to a string another which contains the " ' " characters
the string look as wanted But when I create an Object with this string, I'm getting a "\" inside it:

I check in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285 how to deal with special character

EDIT: 
I made a mistake in understanding the source of my problem...
When I try to build a URL with  URLQueryItem , there Im getting

```
print(EventToUrl.name) // print John's Event
let name = URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: EventToUrl.name)                               
print(name.description) //print name=John's Event
print(name.value) // print Optional("John\'s Event")
deepLink.queryItems = [name]
print(deepLink.url) //print Optional(https://www.example.com/?id%3D-KZXZG2bcuKHNdYNcGTF%26name%3DJohn's%2520Event%26....)
```

And when i try to send this deep link Im getting an error because of the " ' " characters

I also try Eric Aya's answer here : 
[How to use special character in NSURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148999/how-to-use-special-character-in-nsurl)
but that not working for me:

```
print(EventToUrl.name)  //print "John's Event"
let name = URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: EventToUrl.name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed))
print(name.description) //Print name=John's%20Event
print(name.value) //Print Optional("John\'s%20Event")
print(deepLink.url)    //print
    Optional(https://www.example.com/?id%3D-KZXWVbBolmso5DT4p2I%26name%3John's%252520Event%26.......)
```

Self contained code :

```
var urlTestComponents = URLComponents()
urlTestComponents.scheme = "https"
urlTestComponents.host = "www.example.com"
urlTestComponents.path = "/"
let nameTest = URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: "John's Event")
urlTestComponents.queryItems = [name]
print(urlTestComponents.url)
```

The last line prints "https://www.example.com/?name=jeremie's%20Event" and If I try to send that (with whatsApp) the url is cut at the middle because of the " ' "

: [image: url cut]

Comment: Is `event3W.name` an *optional* property? Then this would be just an artefact of the print function.

Comment: @MartinR , Im not sure what do you mean by artefact , I edit my question with my Event class

Comment: Show us how the Event init is done, and what type is the name property, please.

Comment: @EricAya , just add the edit

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, it prints ok for me.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me in the playground.

Comment: Its strange , Im gonna check it maybe its coming from another pliece of code

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @OOPer using xcode 8.1

Comment: @EricAya I find where my problem is coming from , please see my  edit if you can help me

Comment: THERE IS NO PROBLEM! As I guessed, `name.value` is an optional. Optionals use a different description method for their contents with different escaping rules.    That applies *only* to the print statement. Try `print(name.value!)` for confirmation.

Comment: @MartinR when I try to share that url , It is getting crop in the middle  because of the " ' " character : here an example : https://kh6rp.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.example.com/?id%3D-KZXilWEFZJRkKfGRUnV%26name%3DJohn's%2520Event%26***%3D%26created%3D%26participants%3D2%26place%3D***%2520Office%26***%3D1482346356.39613&apn=***&ibi=***&d=1

Comment: @jerem: I don't see where the `%2520` comes from – it doesn't in my test, perhaps I am overlooking something. Can you post *self-contained* code which creates the problematic URL request? And what error do you get exactly?

Comment: var urlTestComponents = URLComponents()
        urlTestComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlTestComponents.host = "www.example.com"
        urlTestComponents.path = "/"
        print(EventToUrl.name)
        let nameTest = URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: EventToUrl.name)
        print(name.description)
        print(name.value)
        urlTestComponents.queryItems = [name]
        print(urlTestComponents.url)

Comment: @MartinR that my self contained code , if I try to send this URL , I get the crop because of the " ' " character :  https://   www.   example.  com/     ?name=John's%20Event

Comment: It is not self-contained code with `EventToUrl.name`. And please add the code to your question itself. – What does "I get the crop" mean?

Comment: @MartinR I add to my code! Thanks for trying to help , Really!

Comment: @jerem: I probably cannot help anymore. As far as I know, a single-quote does not have to be escaped in a URL, so this *could* be a problem with the WhatsApp API (and I have *no* experience with that). I only would like to point out that the backslash is not the problem, it does not appear in the final url.