# WebView: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change my WebView URL, but every time I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

What's wrong? Thanks.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebView.delegate = self
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://cnn.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
    myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest);

}

func changeURL(urlIncome:String) {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlIncome)
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
        myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest);
}
```

My `AppDelegate` code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var vc = ViewController()


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "", handleNotificationReceived: { (notification) in

        let payload = notification?.payload
        //let fullMessage = payload?.title
        if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData, let actionURL = additionalData["url"] as? String {
            self.vc.changeURL(urlIncome: actionURL);
        }

    }, handleNotificationAction: { (result) in

        // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
        let payload = result?.notification.payload
        let fullMessage = payload?.title

        NSLog(fullMessage!);

    }, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : true, kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : false])



    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Comment: In which line you get that crash ? What is the value of urlIncome ?

Comment: Is urlIncome a valid url? If not NSURL(string: urlIncome) will return nil and you get the error you see)

Comment: Note: don't force downcast URL and URLRequest. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812286/swift-3-urlsession-shared-ambiguous-reference-to-member-datataskwithcomplet/37812485#37812485 and percent encode your URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30149081/2227743

Comment: @mlidal Yes, valid URL `http://nyt.com`

Comment: @MidhunMP `http://nyt.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code I've just tested in **Swift 3** with `Deployment Target 9.0` set into **General** tab in **XCode 8.2**. It works smoothly, hope this helps:

**your ViewController.swift:**

```
var myUrl = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if myUrl == "" {
let url = URL (string: "http://cnn.com")
webView.delegate = self
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!)) 
} else {
let url = URL (string: myUrl)
webView.delegate = self
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!)) 
}

    }
```

**AppDelegate:**

```
if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData, let actionURL = additionalData["url"] as? String {
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let myVC : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
myVC.myUrl = actionURL
         self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
         self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Also remember to add **App Transport Security** into your `Info.plist` file in order to allow Arbitrary Loads (unless you've already done that :)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Simply doesn't work. I'm calling the changeURL from my AppDelegate when I receive a push.

Comment: Show the code in the app delegate where you are calling `changeURL`.  You're probably doing it wrong there which is causing `myWebView` to be `nil`.

Comment: ok, i thought you called that changeURL() func from the same swift file that hosts your webView. Then you should check if the code you have for received notifications works fine with a print() func, and post that code as @dan said

Comment: @dan Updated my question. Sorry for forgetting that guys.

Comment: ok so first put a print(actionURL) into if let additionalData and check if prints something. if not, that's where the error is, and you should check the OneSignal documentation or contact them, they usually reply within a day

Comment: @fvimagination Prints the url I expect.

Comment: @fvimagination It gives me 2 errors in code: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'myUrl'` in `myVC.myUrl = actionURL` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'initialViewControlleripad`

Comment: have you added the "ViewController" Storyboard ID in the inspector panel? http://timdietrich.me/fmblog/assets/swift-multiple-storyboards-03.png

Comment: @fvimagination Yes, I am.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its crashing is because you are force casting URL and URL request.

Change the below code

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://cnn.com");
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL);
myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest);
```

to

```
let url = URL(string: "http://google.com")!
myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

Comment: Can you try with other URL.Can you tell me where you are facing error.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be your code. I put a breakpoint and didn't point any error.

Comment: When I put breakpoint on `myWebView.loadRequest`, it gives me `myWebView UIWebView! nil`

Comment: @LucasVeiga, is `myWebView` linked in xib/Storyboard?

Comment: @user28434 Yes because it loads at first. The issue happens when I try to change the URL.

Comment: @LucasVeiga, can you try putting `didSet` block for `myWebView`, and check `when` it becomes `nil`?

Comment: @user28434 Sorry, I'm new in swift. How can I do this?

Comment: @LucasVeiga, [properties documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html), section `Property Observers`