# WKWebView not opening URL with devanagari font in URL

Tags: ios, swift, url, wkwebview

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway integration of a bank. But the `WKWebView` doesn't load the URL.

The URL which I am trying to load in `WKWebView` is

Here is URL:
[http://www.mpenagarpalika.gov.in/EasyPay20/EncDataPage.jsp?copr_id=3163&requestId=XXXX&customerRefNo=XXXX&amount=3937.000&version=1.0&type=PRD&currency=INR&returnURL=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mpenagarpalika.gov.in%2fwt_easypay1res%2fgetdecrypt&prePopulatedInfo=1000000001%7c0274%7cW10000011447%7cINR%7c3937.000&reserveField1=MN&reserveField2=WTax&reserveField3=Water_Tax&reserveField4=समीम&reserveField5=वार्ड%20क्र%2006%20%20जवाहरलाल&bankReferenceNumber=W10000011447&fromSenderIP=99.199.255.199](http://www.mpenagarpalika.gov.in/EasyPay20/EncDataPage.jsp?copr_id=3163&requestId=XXXX&customerRefNo=XXXX&amount=3937.000&version=1.0&type=PRD&currency=INR&returnURL=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mpenagarpalika.gov.in%2fwt_easypay1res%2fgetdecrypt&prePopulatedInfo=1000000001%7c0274%7cW10000011447%7cINR%7c3937.000&reserveField1=MN&reserveField2=WTax&reserveField3=Water_Tax&reserveField4=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AE&reserveField5=%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%2006%20%20%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2&bankReferenceNumber=W10000011447&fromSenderIP=99.199.255.199)

When I try to run the same URL on laptop browser then it's working fine.

I have tried these options:

```
let hiturl = paymentPageURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]{} ").inverted)

let hiturl = paymentPageURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try .urlPathAllowed?

Comment: Yes I tried. Its not working

Comment: .urlPathAllowed won't work in this case. I believe you need to encode your devanagiri parameters before adding them to the URL, this is new to me.

Comment: try using this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30149081/1042817

Comment: I already referred this question. This is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just bring a tested solution for you. Please try below code:

```
let sampleURL = "http://www.mpenagarpalika.gov.in/EasyPay20/EncDataPage.jsp?copr_id=3163&requestId=XXXX&customerRefNo=XXXX&amount=3937.000&version=1.0&type=PRD&currency=INR&returnURL=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mpenagarpalika.gov.in%2fwt_easypay1res%2fgetdecrypt&prePopulatedInfo=1000000001%7c0274%7cW10000011447%7cINR%7c3937.000&reserveField1=MN&reserveField2=WTax&reserveField3=Water_Tax&reserveField4=समीम&reserveField5=वार्ड%20क्र%2006%20%20जवाहरलाल&bankReferenceNumber=W10000011447&fromSenderIP=99.199.255.199/"

if let encoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed),
            let myURL = URL(string: encoded)
        {
            print(myURL)
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
            myWebView.load(myRequest)
        }
```

And one more important thing, please don't forget to add below lines in `info.plist` for lazy loading, otherwise WKWebView can't able to load the url.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution to this is: all the characters in url which are in different language should be base64 encoded.

Comment: Not my vote but your answer would be a lot better if you showed the needed code to make this work.

Comment: base64 encoding might work for you but will it work for everyone? I mean easypay accepts base64 encoded content and decodes it. Again not my down vote.